# Как прочитать данные, постоянно поступающие через com-порт?

Tags: c#, .net, serial

Всем доброго времени суток!

Небольшая вводная:
Имеется система, которая постоянно высылает сообщения об состоянии самой системы и элементах, которые входят в нее.
Условно назовем эти сообщения "посылками". Размер посылки не фиксирован. Все посылки состоят из фреймов, каждая посылка может содержать любое количество фреймов, но обязательным является наличие стартового и финального фрейма. Все виды фреймов имеют строго фиксированную длину и уникальный первый байт.
Стартовый фрейм - 11.
Финальный фремй - С9.

Теперь немного аппаратной части:
Скорость передачи - 19200, стартовые биты -1, стоповые биты - 2, контроль четности - нет. Между "посылками" имеется пауза в 1.5 байта. Если в этот промежуток нужное устройство не отправило сообщение, линию занимает следующее за ним.

Теперь сам вопрос:

Как принимать всю "посылку" от паузы до паузы???

Пробовал несколько способов:
1. Просто читать данные через Read и писать это в массив, а затем уже определять известные флаги и делить на посылки и фреймы. Но данный способ не очень нравится, тк нет никакой информации о моменте паузы в передаче, а без нее в будущем не возможно будет отправлять данные в систему.
2. Использовал port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceviedHandler). Все остальные попытки были проделаны именно таким способом. Менялась только логика DataReceviedHandler.
Тестировал на консоли, выводил данные из буфера в новую строку, но посылки разорваны, например конец первой может содержаться в следующей строке и тд.

Настройки порта:

port.BaudRate = 19200;
port.DataBits = 8;
port.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
port.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.Two;

Остальные настройки пробовал менять, но никаких изменений. Не смог понять как обрабатывать стартовый бит, тк ранее в подобных системах его не было, или все работало без него, а на мдсн такой информации не нашел. Еще хотелось бы попробовать изменить ReadTimeout, но не смог разобраться какое значение выставить.

Вот пример работы. В середине строки видим флаг 11 - это указывает на начало стартового фрейма, и, собственно начало посылки. Ошибки в данных нет, проверяю через расчет CRC. Через 8 байт идет флаг C9 - это финальный фрейм. Но почему его окончание идет в следующей посылке??

[image: Пример работы]

Буду признателен и благодарен за помощь!

Comment: В аппаратной части есть буфер, плюс у операционной системы есть буферизация, поэтому COM может бить пакет на любое колличество байт. Прийдётся делать детект начала, конца, и возможно поставить лимит на длинну сообщения.

Comment: То есть определить момент, когда в систему будет пауза между посылками программно невозможно? придется реализовать это аппаратно?

Comment: Ваш аппаратный пакет система может "порвать" паузой (что видно на скрине). Думаю нужно делать фильтр на 11 и С9, лимитировать пакет и проверять сумму.

Comment: Мне в вашем протоколе видится определённая проблема. Дело в том, что пауза в 1.5 секунд на _передаче_ совсем не означает такую же паузу на _приёме_. Любой компьютер может быть занят полторы секунды срочными вещами (например, заблокирован антивирусом). Так что полагаться на паузу нельзя.

Comment: И то же касается и отправляющей стороны. Таким образом, у нас получается в сухом остатке просто поток данных от разных источников. И встаёт вопрос о том, возможно ли перекрытие данных, и как узнать, кто в данный момент занимается передачей.